# How to read specific column and cell in mysql in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, select, executereader

I use `ExecuteReader` to select all (SELECT*) for all field like this

```
string query = "SELECT* FROM tb_patient_information ";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        { //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            { ... }
```

but I only want to select in specific column and cell like in red square.. like this picture[image: I only want to select in specific cell&column like in red square]

Comment: Why not use mysql to achieve the column part? SELECT [ColumnName] FROM tb_patient_information

Comment: Suggestion: Never use * to select in your programs, specify the column names specifically. This way your program won't crash or have unexpected functionality if the table changes (and you don't have to remember to change several things).

Comment: but I only want to select in specific column and cell like in red square

Answer (score 3):

You can get the specific column inside the `while` clause.

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{ 
    var _column = dataReader["Nama_Kategori"];
}
```

Comment: but I only want to select in specific column and cell like in red square (see my picture)

Comment: why are you not filtering the result with `WHERE` clause eg `SELECT * FROM tb_patient_information WHERE ID_Kategori = 'KI-02'`?

Comment: I mean : SELECT* FROM tb_patient_information .so this code will display many line, and I only want to select 3rd line..

Comment: yes, it selects all records, why not filter it using `WHERE`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using

```
        string query = "SELECT column FROM tb_patient_information ";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        { 
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dataReader.Read())
            { 
                dataReader.ExecuteScalar();
             }
        }
```

or use `dataReader["columnName"]`

Comment: but I only want to select in specific column and cell like in red square (see my picture)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExecuteScalar()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executescalar) of MySqlCommand method to retieve single value

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Nama_Kategori FROM tb_patient_information WHERE Id_kategori = 'KI-02'", myConnection);
myCommand.Connection.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: but I only want to select in specific column and cell like in red square (see my picture)

Comment: Thank you @voo but TOP only in SQL not in mySQL

Comment: @YanPayjo If your Id_kategori is a primary key, then making it a select field will return you only 1 row without TOP

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Query**

If you want only third row data then try the below query :

```
Select * from (Select row_number() over (order by subssn) as rownum, * FROM 
tb_patient_information)result Where rownum = 3
```

-This Query return the 3rd row on Result Set

**In DataReader**

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{ 
string Id = dataReader["Id_kategori"].ToString();
string Name = dataReader["Nama_Kategori"].ToString();
}
```

**OR** 
IF You Say **I only use `Select * from tb_patient_information` and i need 3rd row result**  Then try like below

```
         int count=1;  
         while (dataReader.Read())  
          {  

            if(count == 3)
            {
             string Id = dataReader["Id_kategori"].ToString();
             string Name = dataReader["Nama_Kategori"].ToString();
            }  
           count ++;  
          }
```

Comment: but I only want to select in specific column and cell like in red square (see my picture)