# How can I get MySQL cell value by column name in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Right now, I'm using a `MySqlDataReader` to read the result from a query and using `reader.GetInt()`, `reader.GetString()`, etc. to get the value of each cell like so:

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read()) {
   myfirstvalue = reader.GetInt32(0);
   mysecondvalue = reader.GetString(1);
   mythirdvalue = reader.GetString(2);
   ...
}
```

This works and all, but it kind of grabs the values blindly. You might get an unexpected value if the order of the results gets changed.

Can I retrieve the returned results by column name? Back in my PHP days, you could get an array and access the values like `$results['mycolumn']`. Is this possible in C#?

Comment: sure http://i.imgur.com/RKVo4uz.jpg

Comment: You're looking for [GetOrdinal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_GetOrdinal.htm)...but the _"order of the results gets changed"_ should really not be an issue if you are handling queries safely. Also, keep in mind if you're looping through a lot of results, you may want to just get the ordinals once, not on every field access of every row.

Comment: Yes. The datareader order will always be in the order of the SELECT statement (eg SELECT col2, col3, col5 FROM mytable will produce reader[0] = col2, reader[1] = col3, reader[2] = col5). But you can also access as reader["col2"] UPDATE - was thinking SQL... use GetOrdinal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read specific column and cell in mysql in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904333/how-to-read-specific-column-and-cell-in-mysql-in-c)

Comment: The MySqlDataReader has these overloads of the GetXXXX methods that accepts a column name. Just try.

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked the override allowing you to get by the column name.

Comment: @bwoogie you can use reader["CompanyName"]

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946108/c-sharp-mysql-get-value-from-column-if-status-is-a